# Coordinating multiple VMs in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using a CloudFormation stack that deploys 3 EC2 VMs.  Each needs to be configured to be able to discover the other 2, either via IP or hostname, doesn't matter.

Amazon's private internal DNS seems very unhelpful, because it's based on the IP address, which can't be known at provisioning time.  As a result, I can't configure the nodes with just what I know at CloudFormation stack time.

As far as I can tell, I have a couple of options.  All of them seem to me more complex than necessary - are there other options?

1. Use Route53, set up a private DNS hosted zone, make an entry for each of the VMs which is attached to their network interface, and then by naming the entries, I should know ahead of time the private DNS I assign to them.
2. Stand up yet another service to have the 3 VMs "phone home" once initialized, which could then report back to them who is ready.
3. Come up with some other VM-based shell magic, and do something goofy like using nmap to scan the local subnet for machines alive on a certain port.

On other clouds I've used (like GCP) when you provision a VM it gets an internal DNS name based on its resource name in the deploy template, which makes this kind of problem extremely trivial.  Boy I wish I had that.

What's the best approach here?   (1) seems straightforward, but requires people using my stack to have extra permissions they don't really need.  (2) is extra resource usage that's kinda wasted.  (3) Seems...well goofy.

Comment: You can request a specific private IP for each of the EC2 instances when you launch it, if you prefer that approach. Or you can change hostnames (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html).

Comment: @jarmod changing hostnames appears not to be an option; works locally to the VM, but other VMs can't resolve that hostname. Private IPs, that does seem workable, and similar to (1) in that it requires provisioning/paying/permissioning new resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use Route53, set up a private DNS hosted zone, make an entry for each of the VMs which is attached to their network interface, and then by naming the entries

This is the best solution, but there's a simpler implementation.

1. Give each of your machines a "resource name".
2. In the CloudFormation stack, create a `AWS::Route53::RecordSet` resource that associates a hostname based on that "resource name" to the EC2 instance via its logical ID.
3. Inside your application, use the resource-name-based hostname to access the other isntance(s).

An alternative may be to use an Application Load Balancer, with your application instances in separate target groups. The various EC2 instances then send all traffic through the ALB, so you only have one reference that you need to propagate (and it can be stored in the UserData for the EC2 instance). But that's a lot more work.

This assumes that you already have the private hosted zone set up.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are talking about is known as service discovery.

If you deploy the EC2 instances in the same subnet in the same VPC with the same security group that allows the port the want to communicate over, they will be "discoverable" to each other.

You can then take this a step further. If autoscaling is on the group and machines die and respawn they can write there IPs into a registry i.e. dynamo so that other machines will know where to find them.

Comment: Elasticsearch has an EC2 plug-in that does exactly this - it uses instance metadata and tagging to discover other nodes.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about service discovery for sure.  What you say is true, but *how* will they be discoverable without an extra service?  How can node 1 predict the network location of node 2 and 3?  That's the question -- not just how to make it network possible.